# Best approach to converting Web API into Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-functions

I'm working on converting our WebAPI endpoints into Azure Functions.
Our WebApi has a number of Custom Attributes that handle authentication, how to convert these to Azure Functions?

As an example, here is an AuthorizeAttribute:

```
public class MyAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
        public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (!AuthorizationHelper.SkipAuthorization(actionContext))
            {
                // Some auth logic here generating a ClaimsPrincipal omitted..
                HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
                await base.OnAuthorizationAsync(actionContext,cancellationToken);
            }
       }
}
```

In WebAPI: `HttpContext.Current.User` to get the calling user
In Azure Functions: no HttpContext

Comment: I have an [Azure Functions app authenticating with Auth0 here](https://github.com/StephenClearyExamples/FunctionsAuth0). It's one approach you could start with.

Comment: This is a great question. Too bad it was flagged and closed down.

Comment: Why was this closed? I was looking for this exact question

Comment: It was deemed too broad, and was never reopened after I edited it. Still haven't found a good solution, but mostly due to lack of trying :)

Comment: it's a good question, edited it to make answerable